# Thunderbolt display firmware update 1.2 keeps reappearing, but is not compatible

Tags: display, software-update, thunderbolt, firmware

I've got a problem with the Thunderbolt display firmware 1.2. My screen is not compatible, because it was purchased in 2012 and the update can not be performed. However, the update keeps reappearing on the App Store updates.

I tried the what [Apple recommends](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203758), however nothing changed and the update keeps posting. Many people are complaining about it. Anyone has an idea how to disable this update?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem: The "Thunderbolt display firmware update 1.2" kept reappearing in AppStore, even though the uppdate seemed successful.

[According to Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204450) the update was successful when the the Firmware Version is 26.2 and the Port Micro Firmware Version is 2.0.7 (visible in About this Mac -> SystemReport).

Above versions were correct in my case, but the update still kept appering in AppStore... (probably I did download and install the update manually after the first failure, but I don't remember ...)

To get rid of the annoying update in AppStore I used the [softwareupdate command](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/softwareupdate.8.html) on the commandline:

```
softwareupdate --ignore TBdisplayFWUpdate1.2
```

The update package name may vary. For example:

```
softwareupdate --ignore ThunderboltFirmwareUpdate1.2
```

To find the correct name of the update for your machine, use the following command and copy the update package name up until the "-"

```
softwareupdate -l
```

Comment: You don't need to use Terminal. You can right click the update in App Store and select Hide Update.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party, but this is what worked for me. Hope it helps:

1. Download the update from https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1775?locale=en_US
2. Shut down your Mac. Unplug Thunderbolt display.
3. Boot back up, with your Mac lid/screen open (with Thunderbolt display still unplugged).
4. Plug in your Thunderbolt display. Run the update/installer. Installer will prompt a restart.
5. Restart.
6. Finally, check the update installed correctly (see: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204450). Also check for any outstanding software updates (and sort them whilst you're there).

Comment: This did not work for me. After following the steps Thunderbolt Display `Firmware Version` remains at `22.2`. The `Port Micro Firmware Version` is `0.0.21`. Maybe my current firmware is too old?